# Changing only font styles with a font dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a note-taking app with c# forms. I want it to be almost fully customisable so I included a font dialog. But if the user selects higher font sizes than what I set. Buttons and labels looks very bad. So what I want is if the user wants to change the font, only the font style will be applied.[A photo of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0rbl.png)

```
private void font_change_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fontDialog1.ShowApply = true;
            fontDialog1.MaxSize = 40;
            fontDialog1.MinSize = 8;
            if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
            {
                title.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
                message.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
            }
        }

private void fontDialog1_Apply(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                title.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
                message.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
            
        }
```

Comment: I think taking the ability to change the font size away from the user is a really bad decision WRT to usability.  Some people will need to make the font size bigger so they can read it.

Comment: @JJF I'm sorry that details are too broad. But I have no problem with textbox fontsize. Instead I have problems with button and label fontsize.

Comment: Use `title.Font = new Font(fontDialog1.Font.FontFamily, title.Font.Size, fontDialog1.Font.Style);`.

Comment: Maybe don't allow them to use your app to change the font on buttons and labels?  Just let them default to the system font/font size which the user can set for the entire system.  Then if the user makes them so big that it looks bad?  Well that the prerogative of the user isn't it?  I would rather have an ugly interface I can read and use rather than a beautiful one I can't even see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before button click

[image: Before button click]

After button click

[image: After button click]

The Code

```
label1.Font = new Font("Yu Gothic", label1.Font.Size);
```

SO, We are only changing the font family while current font size will be the same. You Can do same with buttons on performing your action. Hope it works!